# events.js:142 error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, web-frontend

I have a file , in javascript , that find all the directories that match the parameter.

And i got this error:

[image]

my code:

```
    function getUserHome() {
        return process.env[(process.platform == 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'];
    }

var home_path=getUserHome();

var findit  = require('findit'),
    path    = require('path'),
    finder  = findit(path.resolve(home_path));
    var myArgs = process.argv.slice(2)[0];
    var  filter1 = new RegExp(myArgs);

    //This listens for directories found
    finder.on('directory', function (dir) {
        var directories = dir.split('\\');
        var last= directories[directories.length-1].toLowerCase();

        if(filter1.test(last)){
            console.log('Directory: ' + dir );

        }
    });
```

(My code is a mess, i will clean it later)

How to fix that?

Comment: Can you share some relevant code which might cause the error?

Comment: It means something that uses an event handler threw an error. You'll have to share the code causing the problem for us to help. But it looks like you don't have permission to access that file.

Comment: Yup, please show us some code of your script. This error is not helpful enought but a "generic" one

Comment: Which Windows do you use ?

Comment: @Chilipote windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Why you didn't user the fs from Node, and look for dirs recursively? I think the error should be on the findit module...

That a look on https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback or try instead the https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir that also does it. I think that the things you use from the module findit, will be available there (like ways to ignore files)...

EDIT1: Example using recursive-readdir:

```
var recursive = require('recursive-readdir');

var filter1 = new RegExp(myArgs);
function ignoreFunc(file, stats) {
  return !(stats.isDirectory() && filter1.test(path.basename(file)));
}

recursive('directory', [ignoreFunc] ,function (err, files) {
  // Files is an array of filename (only the ones that matched the condition)
  console.log(files);
});
```

Comment: I use the fs before, i want get only the folders path . without the files inside.

Comment: So give a try on the recursive-readdir and use the ignore function as stated on their example: function ignoreFunc(file, stats) {
  return !stats.isDirectory();
}

Comment: That function used as `ignoreFunction`, will assure that you only get folders. And you can also do the regex test inside, if you want (meaning that the result of the call, the `files` will be an array of the folders that match that expression)

Comment: I read about it, but i got confused..can you show my example with ignore Function?

Comment: See the edit with the example. I haven't tested it, but it should work as you expect. Or at least, if you receive any error because that stats, you should be able to overpass it now, doing other kind of verification...

Answer (score 0):

@Moran, can you add a `console.log` directly in the callback of you "directory" event ?

```
finder.on('directory', function (dir) {
        // Here 
        console.log(dir);

       var directories = dir.split('\\');
        var last= directories[directories.length-1].toLowerCase();

        if(filter1.test(last)){
            console.log('Directory: ' + dir );

        }
    });
```

To see what directory is problematic ? Then compare the rights applied on this folder and a directory that work, as "comverse" for example. It would help to find your error

Comment: I get all the directories , this a long list. don't see where the problem :\

Comment: Can you compare the rights of the last directory logged in your terminal with the "webstormproject\withcomverse" for example ?

Because I think the last folder display in your terminal will be the problematic one. 

I think because of findit, it try to read inside a folder that you have no rights.

Comment: @Moran, did you find out ?